# Taking user input to create text file names with prewritten name and user input

Tags: python, text-files, user-input

Hi I'm trying to create a couple text files with a prewritten tag along with a given user input. 
For Ex. I need 5 file names with a prewritten tag and the input

Cat100.txt
Where cat is predetermined and the number 100 is the user input.

I have this but I can't find out how to add a prewritten tag along with the user input.

```
filename = input ("filename: ");
with open (filename, "w") as f:
```

Thank you!

Comment: I need the txt file names to take the user input.

Answer (score 2):

Updated per comment clarifications:

```
import os 

folderpath = ".\\test_folder\\"
prewritten_tag  = "User wrote: " # example
user_filename = input("filename: ")
full_filename = prewritten_tag + user_filename
fullpath = os.join(folderpath,full_filename) # gets absolute path

with open(fullpath, "w") as f:
  user_input = input()
  full_txt = stuff + input() + otherstuff
  f.write(full_txt)
```

Comment: I still add the input line like how it is right? Thank you for your help!

Comment: @KevinM If you want to write user input, yes, just as you wrote. To make it more intuitive, you could do `user_input = input()` `full_txt = prewritten_tag + user_input + postwritten_tag`

Comment: OverLoardGoldDragon Is there a way I could make the tag a part of the text file itself not the content?